# how to enable user to read files ONLY from internal storage- Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, storage

I am trying to read PDF files from internal storage using Intents. I want to insert a check in my code that if a user tries to pick file from External source then my app must throw an exception.
How can i do that?
The code that i am using for reading files is as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: "I am trying to read PDF files from internal storage using Intents" -- your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) cannot be accessed by other applications, such as anything responding to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Those apps could access [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and possibly [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), along with their own portions of internal storage.

Comment: Also note that `DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR` is not going to be honored by very many apps.